# Spring JPA - findAll() with example/probe including related/joined entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

How does one go about using a Spring JPA's [Query by Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example)  to query not just the entity itself, but properties on a related entity using `findAll()`? All of our attempts seem to just ignore the related entity properties when they are set on the probe/example entity.

The documentations states:

> The property specifier accepts property names (such as firstname and lastname). You can navigate by chaining properties together with dots (address.city). You can also tune it with matching options and case sensitivity.

However, there is no example show how the chaining should work, and our attempts to use it have yielded no success.

**Contrived Example**

Assuming a database structure with a many-to-many relationship:

- Table: Book

  - id (PK, INT)
  - title (varchar)
  - ...
- Table: Category

  - id (PK, INT)
  - name
  - ...
- Table: Book_Category

  - book_id
  - category_id

**Book.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Book {
    public Book () {}
    public Book(String title, List<Category> categories) {
        this.title = title;
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
        name = "book_category",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")}
    )
    private List<Category> categories;
}
```

**BookRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public class BookRepository extends JpaRepository<Book, long> {

}
```

**Category.java**

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;
}
```

**CategoryRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public class CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<Category, long> {

}
```

**BookService.java**

```
public class BookService {
    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    public List<Book> findByExample(String title, String category) {
        ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matchingAll()
            .withMatcher("title", match -> match.contains().ignoreCase()) 
// ### This is (probably?) the bit that's wrong - none of these made any difference        
            //.withMatcher("categories.id", match -> match.contains()) 
            //.withMatcher("categories.name", match -> match.contains().ignoreCase()) 
            //.withMatcher("categories", match -> match.contains()) 
// ###
            .withIgnoreNullValues() // ignore unset properties when finding
            .withIgnorePaths("id"); // ignore primitives as they default to 0

        List<Category> matchingCategories = categoryRepository.findAllByName(category);
        Example<Book> example = Example.of(new Book(
            title, matchingCategories), matcher);

        return bookRepository.findAll(example)
    }
}
```

Calling the BookService.findByExample(...) correctly filters based on title, but completely ignores the category. The "real" example is more complex but this distills the issue we're having; how can we filter on the related table as well as the base one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only true for ToOne relationships and does not work for ToMany like in your case:

> The property specifier accepts property names (such as firstname and
>   lastname). You can navigate by chaining properties together with dots
>   (address.city). You can also tune it with matching options and case
>   sensitivity.

I also had a look at the Spring Data source code and here it is:

```
for (SingularAttribute attribute : type.getSingularAttributes()) {
```

So it only uses SingularAttribute like primitives, String and ToOne relationships.

So I'm afraid but what you try to achieve seems not be possible.